# How to turn off tool tip for the Identify button?

Tags: arcgis-engine, development

When using the esriControls.ControlsMapIdentifyTool tool, the (i) button, whenever you click it, it says "Click on or drag a box over a feature and place on the map where you want to identify" in a window...

Is there a way to remove this auto tool tip?  It's totally unnecessary because if you close it and click on a point on the map it will respawn itself with real data.

I'm using ArcEngine 10, C#, & VS2010.